# Missing number, treated as zero for a \loop ... \repeat

Tags: errors, loops

I'm trying to write simple macros, which functional is to print every n = n + k-th letter from the alphabet, where k and n are counters. 
So I need a `\loop`-`\repeat` construction. I use it, but it works incorrectly unfortunately.

The main error is "missing number, treated as zero" in row with a `\repeat` command written. I also tried without using the `\value{n}` function - the same result.

Any ideas how to fix it to work fine?

Here is my code:

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[english, russian]{babel}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}
    \newcounter{n}
    \newcounter{k}
    \setcounter{k}{1}
    \setcounter{n}{0}
    \loop
    \alph{ \value{n} }
    \addtocounter{n}{k}
    \ifnum \value{n} < 26 \repeat
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You use `\value` at the wrong place. You need to use it in the second argument of `\addtocounter` rather than in `\alph`. (I commented out the packages that are not directly related to the problem.)

```
\documentclass{article}
% \usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
% \usepackage[english, russian]{babel}
% \usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}
    \newcounter{n}
    \newcounter{k}
    \setcounter{k}{1}
    \setcounter{n}{0}
    \loop
    \alph{n}
    \addtocounter{n}{\number\value{k}}
    \ifnum \value{n} < 26 \repeat

    Or without spurious spaces:
    \setcounter{n}{0}%
    \loop%
    \alph{n}%
    \addtocounter{n}{\number\value{k}}%
    \ifnum\value{n}<26\repeat
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 3):

The command `\alph` takes as argument a *counter's name*, so `\alph{\value{n}}` is incorrect and should be `\alph{n}`.

The command `\addtocounter` takes two arguments; the first argument is the name of the counter LaTeX should act on, the second argument should be an integer (in any possible denotation); if you want to increment counter `n` by 31, you can do

```latex
\addtocounter{n}{31}
\addtocounter{n}{"1F} % hexadecimal
\addtocounter{n}{'37} % octal
\addtocounter{n}{\value{mycounter}}
```

provided `mycounter` currently stores 31. The second argument *cannot* contain just a counter's name.

So you have two calls wrong: `\alph{\value{n}}` (watch out for spaces) should be `\alph{n}`, whereas `\addtocounter{n}{k}` should be `\addtocounter{n}{\value{k}}`.

You also have spurious spaces and the order wrong (you won't get `z`):

```latex
\setcounter{k}{1}
\setcounter{n}{0}

\loop
\ifnum\value{n} < 26
\addtocounter{n}{\value{k}}% <--- needed
\alph{n}% <--- needed
\repeat
```